# python read file with block, but end with newline(\n)

Tags: python, file, newline

test.txt is a "\n" split text file:

> f = open('test.txt','r') f.read(256)

But while read 256, the last records may not with full line.

How to read such as:

I set read 256
but when 248 is the "\n"
and 256 the last records not with full line
just read 248, and f.tell() give the 248 position.

Thanks.

Comment: How should the stream know if there's a newline in data it hasn't read yet? And if your file is split into lines, and the lines are significant, why are you reading it in fixed-size blocks?

Comment: You are probably coming from another language where you access files at a low level and need to solve problems like this (maybe C?). In Python, splitting up a file by lines is normal and there are a lot of good ways to do it (examples in the answers below). You'll probably not need to use read() unless you are rolling your own binary format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do you care about efficiency?

here is one way to do it:

```
data=f.read(256)
data=data.splitlines(True)
if data[-1]!=data[-1].splitlines()[-1]:
    #must be newline at end of last line
    data="".join(data)
else:
    data="".join(data[:-1])

print data
```

Comment: yes, i may read large file, and do something else to the read content, if i read line by line, if i read line by line, it will very slow, thanks.

Comment: No worries. I modified it slightly now to use less memory.

Comment: -1 (1) Where's the loop to read the whole file (or at least to read until you have enough whole lines)? (2) `data1` is not defined (3) `data[-1] != data[-1].splitlines()[-1]` is part of a fast file reader??

Comment: sorry it should have been "data" not "data1". It would be interesting to see bench marks, Initially I didn't know he was after pure performance, in fact I thought he was only reading a maximum of 256, so I went for something that showed nice use of splitlines.

Comment: btw john, I don't think the -1 is entirely fair :(, His question didn't necessarily ask for any of those other requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using newlines to split your data, why not read it in the same way?

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
# Now each line in lines is a complete line.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is read complete lines. For this task, you usually do something of this effect.

```
size_so_far = 0
contents = []

for line in open('test.txt'):
      size_so_far += len(line)
      if size_so_far > 256:
         break
      contents.append(line)

contents = "".join(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to read a file with variable-length lines separated by any of `'\n'`, `'\r'` or `'\r\n'` or even a mixture of those is:

```
with open('yourfile.txt', 'rU') as f:
    for line in f:
        do_something_with(f)
        # optional, if you want to bale out after 256 bytes:
        if f.tell() >= 256: break
```

What that does is read large blocks, find the line endings, and yield a line at a time. The underlying code is written in C. I have yet to see any evidence that doing the same thing in Python code would be faster.

Comment: This will go over 256, so is equivalent to f.read(255)+f.readline()